# Communicating between xform and php-server

Tags: php, xforms

I've question about communicating between chiba-3.0.0b2's xforms and php-server
There is a server.php like:

```
<?php
$var1 = isset($_POST['var1']) && is_numeric($_POST['var1']) ? $_POST['var1'] : 0;
$var2 = isset($_POST['var2']) && is_numeric($_POST['var2']) ? $_POST['var2'] : 0;
$sum = $var1 + $var2;
$str = "$var1 + $var2 = $sum";
?>
```

And using these variable in xml-code in the same serer.php-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <sum><?php  echo $str;  ?></sum>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

XHtml-client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xhtml:html
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
    xmlns:events="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="http://www.example.com">
    <xhtml:head>
        <xhtml:title>XForm</xhtml:title>
```

Here begins a model

```
<xforms:model id="model1">
```

Instance containing some variables

```
    <xforms:instance id="submit_inst">
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns="">
            <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <my:start SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                    <var1 xsi:type="xsd:string"></var1>
                    <var2 xsi:type="xsd:string"></var2>
                </my:start>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    </xforms:instance>
```

Binding the instance variables

```
    <xforms:bind id="bind_var1" nodeset="instance('submit_inst')/SOAP-ENV:Body/my:start/var1" />
    <xforms:bind id="bind_var2" nodeset="instance('submit_inst')/SOAP-ENV:Body/my:start/var2" />
```

A sum result instance

```
    <xforms:instance id="result_inst">
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope/>
    </xforms:instance>
```

There is the submition

```
    <xforms:submission
        id="submissionId"
        action="server.php"
        method="post"
        includenamespaceprefixes=""
        ref="instance('submit_inst')"
        mediatype="action=; application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8"
        instance="result_inst"
        replace="instance">
        <xforms:toggle case="case-busy" events:event="xforms-submit" />
        <xforms:toggle case="case-submit-error" events:event="xforms-submit-error" />
        <xforms:toggle case="case-done" events:event="xforms-submit-done" />
    </xforms:submission>
</xforms:model>
```

There is end of model and head and begin of body

Two number inputs and outputs

```
<xforms:input ref="instance('submit_inst')/SOAP-ENV:Body/my:start/var1" bind="bind_var1" />
<xforms:output ref="instance('submit_inst')/SOAP-ENV:Body/my:start/var1" bind="bind_var1" />
<xhtml:br/>
<xforms:input ref="instance('submit_inst')/SOAP-ENV:Body/my:start/var2" bind="bind_var2" />
<xforms:output ref="instance('submit_inst')/SOAP-ENV:Body/my:start/var2" bind="bind_var2" />
<xhtml:br/>
```

button for calling submission

```
<xforms:submit submission="submissionId">
    <xforms:label>Submit</xforms:label>
</xforms:submit>
```

Some cases for loading, for error and for success

```
        <xforms:switch>
            <xforms:case id="case-busy">Loading...</xforms:case>
            <xforms:case id="case-submit-error">Submision error!</xforms:case>
            <xforms:case id="case-done">
                <xforms:output ref="instance('result_inst')/SOAP-ENV:Body/sum"/>
            </xforms:case>
        </xforms:switch>

    </xhtml:body>
</xhtml:html>
```

What to do that php's $_POST is not array() that i.e array('var1'=>2,'var1'=>3,)?? It doesn't work, server does not see sent $_POST-variables.

Answer (score 0):

By default, your XML instances are submitted as XML serialized on the request body.

Is you want to receive the form data as traditional HTML form fields, you should change the `method` attribute to `urlencoded-post` on your submission.

You can find some examples of handling XForms with PHP in http://php.net/manual/en/features.xforms.php

I think this php script from another XForms processor can help to debug the content sent to your server: http://sourceforge.net/p/xsltforms/code/ci/master/tree/src/echo.php